# Access shared library inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, mono, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi3, linphone

**Goal:** 
Deploying a Docker container that can access the hosts shared libraries (liblinphone.so) or can access the installation of liphone on the host.

**Soft-hardware in use:** 
- Raspberry Pi compute module 
- Mono (C#) 
- Linphone with C# wrapper 
- Docker

**Summary:** 
I am writing code for a RPi3 in Mono(C#). This code uses the GPIO's and a linphone installion (a Linphone 
 ARM version is installed on this system). The code does run flawless on native Mono.  My next goal is to run it inside a Docker container. For this I did setup a private Gitlab server, Docker registry and a Gitlab pipeline to make a Docker image. The Docker image gets build without any errors. 
When I run the code it can't find the liblinphone.so file, obviously.. but I don't know how to.

**Docker run command:**

```
docker run --privileged -v /etc/ld.so.cache:/etc/ld.so.cache -v /etc/ld.so.conf.d/:/etc/ld.so.conf.d/ -v /usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/lib/ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock [registry]:5000/[image]:latest
```

I added some volumes where the .so file and some references are located (some volumes aren't necessary). The --privileged part is to access the GPIO's.

**Error:**

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: linphone assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Linphone.Core.linphone_core_set_log_level_mask(uint)
  at Linphone.Core.SetLogLevelMask (System.UInt32 mask) [0x00001] in <5285048db55d447fae3be4c32e253dbd>:0 
  at BlackBox.Phone.CreatePhone (System.String username, System.String password, System.String server, System.Int32 port, System.String agent, System.String version) [0x00001] in <5285048db55d447fae3be4c32e253dbd>:0 
  at BlackBox.BlackBox..ctor (BlackBox.BlackBox+AppFunction appFunction) [0x00198] in <5285048db55d447fae3be4c32e253dbd>:0 
  at BlackBox.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in <5285048db55d447fae3be4c32e253dbd>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: linphone assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Linphone.Core.linphone_core_set_log_level_mask(uint)
  at Linphone.Core.SetLogLevelMask (System.UInt32 mask) [0x00001] in <5285048db55d447fae3be4c32e253dbd>:0 
  at BlackBox.Phone.CreatePhone (System.String username, System.String password, System.String server, System.Int32 port, System.String agent, System.String version) [0x00001] in <5285048db55d447fae3be4c32e253dbd>:0 
  at BlackBox.BlackBox..ctor (BlackBox.BlackBox+AppFunction appFunction) [0x00198] in <5285048db55d447fae3be4c32e253dbd>:0 
  at BlackBox.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in <5285048db55d447fae3be4c32e253dbd>:0
```

My guess is that I can't mount the linphone .so/installation. but instead that I have to mount the docker socket and run it natively on the host. also that didn't get me success (due to ignorance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Dockerfile that builds the container, run the installation commands that install the package that provides the shared library.

Comment: I made my own Docker image with the needed dependencies. The app is running fine now, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To access shared libraries inside docker, below is one of the ways:

1. Use "COPY" command inside Dockerfile to copy the shared libraries/dependencies inside the container. Example: COPY {local_path} {docker_path}
2. Set the environment variable where shared libraries are searched for first before the standard set of directories. For instance for Linux based OS, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used. Environment variables can be set via [Docker's Environment replacement (ENV)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) Example: ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH={docker_path}:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

This is my DockerFile:

```
FROM mono:latest
ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN xbuild BlackBox.csproj
CMD ["mono", "/src/bin/Debug/BlackBox.exe"]
```

So i have to do something like this:

```
FROM mono:latest
ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN apt-get install neededthing another so_on

RUN xbuild BlackBox.csproj
CMD ["mono", "/src/bin/Debug/BlackBox.exe"]
```

Am I right, @Raedwald?